# TELERIK Radgrid strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, radgrid

I have a Radgrid that refuses to make whatever data in row number 16 and 17 (starting counting from 1) to be selectable.
It's only these two rows that lacks the "selectability" e.g. if I delete these two rows (or the data that's in the rows) the new data that happens to end up here shows the same behavior.

Thanks,
Per

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridUserAdmin" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
        AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateHierarchy="True" CellSpacing="0" DataSourceID="dsUsers"
        GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True" Height="700" AllowSorting="True" ShowStatusBar="True"
        GroupingEnabled="False">
        <ExportSettings>
            <Pdf PageWidth="" />
        </ExportSettings>
        <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True">
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="IDUser" DataSourceID="dsUsers" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
            Name="Users">
            <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>
            <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="UserID,ProductID" DataSourceID="dsUserProduct" Name="Products"
                    CommandItemDisplay="Top">
                    <ParentTableRelation>
                        <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="UserID" MasterKeyField="IDUser"></telerik:GridRelationFields>
                    </ParentTableRelation>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                            DataField="UserID" UniqueName="UserID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="ProductID" DataSourceID="dsAllProducts" HeaderText="Product"
                            ListTextField="Name" ListValueField="IDProduct" UniqueName="ProductID">
                        </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this users access to this product?"
                            ButtonType="LinkButton" ButtonCssClass="link" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                            UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="IDUser" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter IDUser column"
                    HeaderText="IDUser" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IDUser" UniqueName="IDUser"
                    Visible="false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="username" FilterControlAltText="Filter username column"
                    HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username" UniqueName="username">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FullName" FilterControlAltText="Filter FullName column"
                    HeaderText="FullName" SortExpression="FullName" UniqueName="FullName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="eMail" FilterControlAltText="Filter eMail column"
                    HeaderText="eMail" SortExpression="eMail" UniqueName="eMail">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this user?" ButtonType="LinkButton"
                    ButtonCssClass="link" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteUser">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                </EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
            <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
        </MasterTableView>
        <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
        <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
        </FilterMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: For anyone with the same problem I found a fix. This problem is within the Telerik MasterTableView control.
I had to add the property HierarchyLoadMode="Client"

Comment: You can post that as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is within the Telerik MasterTableView control. I had to add the property HierarchyLoadMode="Client"